# Regex semicolon and words

Tags: java, regex

I am facing some difficulties because of some regex expression in Java. I want a expression the validates that one or more words are valid and are delimited by semicolon or not.

Examples:

```
VF;VM - Good
VF;GM - Bad
VF,VM - Bad
VF;VM;IF - Good
VF,VM;IF - Bad
```

I tried this one:

```
String regex = "(\\bVM\\b|\\bVF\\b|\\bTV\\b|\\bIM\\b|\\bIF\\b)|\\;";
```

But it doesn't work....

If you can help me I will be thankful.

Comment: Why `VF;VM` is good and `VF;GM` is bad?

Comment: What about `VF;VM;IF;`?

Comment: @Toto: Looking at the attempt, it's just a list, some are valid, some aren't.

Comment: VF;GM is invalid because GM is on the list of words valid...

Comment: VF;VM;IF; is not valid because ends with a semicolon

Comment: OK, but where is the list?

Comment: it seems you just want to validate a csv file on 1) syntax 2) content ?

Comment: I´d just split on `;` and make sure each element of the array is present in this `List` and that it doesn´t end with `;`

Comment: I´d like to validate if a certain strig as a group of words and are delimited by semicolons except the last word

Comment: is not possible to define a group of words in the regex expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want a list of the valid words, and then an optional repeated group starting with a `;` and the list of valid words:

```
String regex = "^(?:\\b(?:VM|VF|TV|IM|IF)\\b)(?:;\\b(?:VM|VF|TV|IM|IF)\\b)*$";
```

That:

- Uses `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end to match the full input.
- Starts with VM, VF, TV, IM, or IF with word boundary assertions on either side.
- Then allows zero or more repeats with a `;` in front of it. All of your examples involve at least two "words," though, so if that's a requirement, change the `*` (repeat zero or more times) to a `+` (repeat one or more times) on the second group.

...and actually, as [Toto points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803731/regex-semicolon-and-words/40803852#comment68828591_40803852), since we're using anchors and defining a specific separator (`;`), we don't need the word boundaries, so simply

```
String regex = "^(?:VM|VF|TV|IM|IF)(?:;(?:VM|VF|TV|IM|IF))*$";
```

...is sufficient, and simpler.

[Example on regex101 (as a JavaScript regex)](https://regex101.com/r/cZ0rPm/1)

Tests:

```
class Example
{
    private static String regex = "^(?:VM|VF|TV|IM|IF)(?:;(?:VM|VF|TV|IM|IF))*$";

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        test("VF;VM", true);
        test("VF;GM", false);
        test("VF,VM", false);
        test("VF;VM;IF", true);
        test("VF,VM;IF", false);
    }

    private static void test(String str, boolean expectedResult) {
        boolean result = str.matches(regex);
        System.out.println(str + " -- " + (result ? "Good" : "Bad") + (result == expectedResult ? " - OK" : " - ERROR"));
    }
}
```

[Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/ob4iZ1)

Comment: Word boundaries are not mandatory here, because of the anchors

Comment: Nice. Depending on the number of possible words, it could be a good idea to generate the regex from a String[] of valid words.

Comment: yes it is the regex that iam looking for, works just fine thanks!

Comment: can i use this regex in pl sql?

Answer (score 1):

This code might be easier to understand and modify than a big RegEx.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class ValidateList
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> validWords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "VM", "VF", "TV", "IM", "IF" }));
        System.out.println(areAllWordsValid("VF;VM;IF", validWords));
        System.out.println(areAllWordsValid("VF;VM;IF;", validWords));
        System.out.println(areAllWordsValid("VF;GM;IF", validWords));
    }

    public static boolean areAllWordsValid(String string, Set<String> validWords) {
        String[] words = string.split(";", -1);
        for (String word : words) {
            if (!validWords.contains(word)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as the accepted answer but collapsed down a little bit:

```
^(?:VF|VM|IF|TV|IM|;)++$
```